# Use word2vec and seq2seq model in Keras

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, keras, word2vec

My purpose is build something like Q&A bot that can generate sentences according to the input sentences of user. I use pre-trained word2vec in gensim for my input of model.
My words are chinese, but I think it doesn't matter to word2vec. 
I first turned each sentence into a 3d-array. The shape is

(sample_n, time_step, word_dim)

```
x = [sentence_1, sentence_2, ... , sentence_n]
sentence = [word_1, word_2, ...]
word = [250 dimensions array]
```

time_step is equal to the length of sequence.The sequences have already done the zero padding. Thus, the length is fixed.

Next, I build a simple seq2seq model like that:
(I said "simple", because it doesn't have any attention layer and feed last output to current input in decoder.)

```
model = Sequential

# Encoder
model.add(LSTM(units=HIDDEN_SIZE, input_shape=(X_TIME_STEP, WORD_DIM), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(units=HIDDEN_SIZE, input_shape=(X_TIME_STEP, WORD_DIM), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(HIDDEN_SIZE, activation="relu"))
model.add(RepeatVector(Y_TIME_STEP))

# Decoder
model.add(LSTM(units=WORD_DIM, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(units=WORD_DIM, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(WORD_DIM, activation="linear")))

optimizer = optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

The loss value was negative during training.
Afterward, I just use training data to do prediction and turn the output vector back to the sentence.
However, the words in sentence are all the same or something weird.

I changed loss function to "mse". It seems that it improved a little bit and at least the loss wasn't negative, but I think that is not a correct way to solve this.
What I can figure out that is the value of word2vec in each dimension is **not between 0 and 1**.

- In order to use "categorical_crossentropy", It need to do normalization with word vector before training and use softmax for activation function of output layer.
  After prediction, convert the normalized vector back to origin(called denormalized?) and then turn it into sentences.
  If this is fine, what method that I can use to normalized?
- just change the loss function or layer that can deal with the unbound value.

I am new to NN and Keras, is there any way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177905/should-i-normalize-word2vecs-word-vectors-before-using-them